# What happens when you "close all windows"

Tags: java, windows, frame

When you right click in the task bar and select "Close all windows", what exactly is going on?

Does it simply fire a window closing event to all open frames? Or is it something like a system.exit? (I know it's not exactly the same as I've noticed some different behavior, such that all frames will get a window_closing event).

How can I replicate this behaviour?

Comment: Can you provide the environment you are referencing? Are you describing an application development ide or a web browser?

Comment: @BrianGerhards I'm talking about Microsoft Windows 8, when there's no longer enough room in the taskbar, (if the option is enabled) similar items will stack together, and right clicking on the stack will give the option to "close all windows". How is this command interacting with my application and it's frames? Is it firing an event? Is there a way to catch and handle this? Is there a way to fire the same event?

Comment: Have you run any debug tools on Windows? Unfortunately I'm in the world of Windows 7 and can't provide a good answer. Do you have a specific need for running the Windows script and not building one? You will need to follow a similar process including identifying the process and closing all with a similar process label, which is my assumption for the close all windows without debugging it. You may want to consider looking into how to handle prompts that may occur when you close all windows. This is not something that is handled when you click thsi command. You can handle this with custom code.

Comment: @BrianGerhards doesn't windows 7 do it too? I want to know more for curiosity then any real applicable reason. I would just like to know for the future what is happening, that way if a need does arise to handle it differently I can do so. What debug tools would you suggest?